# How to open remote shell to node.js container under docker-compose (Alpine linux)

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a `docker-compose.yml` configuration file with several containers and one of the containers is node.js docker instance.

By some reason the docker instance returns error during start. In the result it's not possible to connect to the node.js container and investigate issue.

What is the simplest way to connect to the broken `node.js` under Alpine linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## FOR DOCKER-COMPOSE

In case if you use `docker-compose` the simplest way is to add the following `command` line into your `docker-compose.yml` file.

```
services:
  api:
    build: api/.
    command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "while sleep 3600; do :; done"]
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
    ...
```

also it need to comment line by line from bottom up inside the `Dockerfile` for `node.js` until the container will be able to start.

After the node.js container will be able to start you can easy connect to your container via

```
docker exec -it [container] sh
```

## FOR DOCKER

You can simply add at the end of `Dockerfile` the following line

```
CMD echo "^D for exit" && wc -
```

and comment line by line (from bottom up) above this line until the container will be able to start.

Answer (score 1):

Usually in my `docker-compose.yml`

I just replace the **command** or **entrypoint** by :

```
command: watch ps
```

It's a bit hackish, but that keeps the container up.

Alternatively, once the image has been built, you can run it using docker. But then you have to do what you did in your docker-compose.yml file in your command, like mount volumes and open ports manually.

Comment: I like your solution

Answer (score -1):

You can [`docker-compose run`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/) an alternate command.  This requires no changes in your `Dockerfile` or `docker-compose.yml`.  For example,

```
docker-compose run --rm web /bin/sh
```

This creates a new container which is configured identically to what is requested in the `docker-compose.yml` (with environment variables and mounted volumes), except that `ports:` aren't published by default.  It is essentially identical to `docker run` with the same options, except it defaults to `-i -t` being on.

If your Dockerfile uses `ENTRYPOINT` instead of `CMD` to declare the main container command, you need the same `--entrypoint` option.  For example, to get a listing of the files in the image's default working directory, you could

```
docker-compose run --rm --entrypoint /bin/ls web -l
```

(If your `ENTRYPOINT` is a wrapper script that ultimately `exec "$@"` you don't need this.)

Comment: Your solution works only if you can build container, but usually you need to find and fix problem when you have problems with build.

Comment: The hex numbers that `docker build` prints out every third line or so are image IDs, so you can `docker run --rm -it 123456789abc sh` to get a shell in a temporary container based on the last succeeding build stage.